# Specify conditional probabilities $P(B_i \mid A_k)$ and calculate $P(B_i \cap A_k)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> $X_t$  is the amount of transmitted particles in a specific time unit,
>   described by $$\pi(X_t=k)=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\cdot e^{-\lambda}$$
>
> $p$ is the probability that a transmitted particle is monitored. $A_k$
>   is the event that exactly $k$ particles are transmitted. $B_i$ is the
>   event that exactly $i$ particles are monitored.
>
> Specify the conditional probabilities $P(B_i \mid A_k)$ and calculate $P(B_i \cap A_k)$

I think the formula in question is poisson distribution? Because I find on internet the same formula but it have no $\pi$. Is it important or is only part of name?

Anyway I think conditional probability of it is just $$P(B_i \mid A_k)=\frac{P(B_i \cap A_k)}{P(A_k)}$$

Now need calculate $P(B_i \cap A_k)$ also. How do it good?

I think because the events $A_k$ and $B_i$ are dependent we need use other way, we need use the conditional probability also.

We get $$P(B_i \cap A_k) = P(B_i) \cdot P(A_k \mid B_i) = P(B_i \mid A_k) \cdot P(A_k)$$

Is this solutions good? No sure because all confused notation and question..

Comment: They are (oddly) using $\pi$ to refer to the probability mass function $P(X_t=k)$ not the *number* $\pi$. What you are asking is to find the number of monitored particles $Y(t)=\sum_1^{N(t)} X_k$ where $N$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda$ and $X_k$ are IID Bernoulli with parameter $p$. It is well known that given $N=n$ then $Y$ is binomial$(n,p)$. Can you conclude how to find $P(B_i|A_n)$, now?